# Is it possible to use the same variable in two different javascript blocks?

Tags: javascript, php, sql, web

I am developing a web that has to show an sql view, so I did the query with PHP, but I have to show the result in charts, and I am trying to use the google geochart. So basically what I want to do is:

1. Select the data from an SQL view with PHP.
2. Get the data from PHP into a javascript variable so I can use it in the chart.
3. Get the value of the javascript variable to put in the google chart api, so it show what I want.

So far, I've got the point 1 and the point 2 (I think) done. But when I am trying to use the javascript variable again in another part of the code it has no value, so no data is showing, I am getting `undefined`on the explorer.

Relevant Code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php
    //connections and stuff

$tsql="SELECT count(*) as Qty, ShipCountry FROM [Orders Qry] group by ShipCountry"; // yes, is the Northwind database example
    $stmt = sqlsrv_query($conn, $tsql);
   if ($stmt === false)
   {
     FatalError("Failed to query table: ".$tsql);
   }
   else
   {
       $json=array();
       $i=0;
       echo "<script type='text/javascript'> var countries = []; </script>";
      while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
      {
        echo "<script> countries[".$i."]= ". $row['ShipCountry'] .";</script>";           
        $i=$i+1;
      }          
      //echo "<h1>". $json["ShipCountry"] ."</h1>"; //I was testing, so the problem is not in retrieving the data from the database.
      sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
   }
?>
<p>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.write(countries[0]);
    </script>
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Not that i tested your script yet. Try removing the 'var' from the script. Instead of var countries = 'blah blah' use countries = 'blah blah' let me know if it works

Comment: No, it's not working.

Comment: @AryehArmon the `var` is needed in JavaScript to introduce a variable. Are you thinking of CoffeeScript, maybe?

Comment: Actually if you do not use the 'var' before the declaration it is a global variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to quote ***$row['ShipCountry']*** (seems to be a string);

```php
echo "<script> countries[".$i."]= '". $row['ShipCountry'] ."';</script>";
```

Note the new quotes.

Comment: Nice one, I thought it was something of the javascript, I am really beginner at web development.

Comment: @El_Mochiq then the JavaScript console will be your friend. :-) Get used to look at it regularly, it often has valuable stuff to tell you!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider using AJAX to query a different file from within your javascript, cf. http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_php.asp.

If you have your PHP file return JSON to the AJAX request, javascript will have an object that it understands and you can use it there. This way you can have all your javascript in one place. E.g. this **pseudo** code:

Javascript.js

```
function gimmeACountry(i){
  var countries = AJAX.get('countries.php');
  return countries[i];
}
```

PHP.php

```
<?php
    $result = mysql_stuff(...);
    print json_encode(result);
?>
```

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src='Javascript.js'>
</head>
<body onload="document.write(gimmeACountry(0));">
</body>
</html>
```

If you really want to use just one file, a few thoughts:

- You don't need to open and close a  statement every time you write javascript. All of your PHP could be embedded in one.
- You can output most of your javascript outside of the  block, instead of echoing everything. I think the PHP is clearer then. E.G.

  `<script>
   <?php $foo = 'bar'; ?>
   var foo = <?php echo $foo ?>;
   document.write(foo); // writes 'bar'
   </script>`
- If you are still have scope issues, you can try adding your variable to the window object, e.g.

  window.countries = []

This might be problematic if you end up doing more stuff with javascript later. I really do recommend you use AJAX.

Comment: Seems like the right way to do it, I'll give a try and let you know if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Distributing javascript over two blocks works fine:

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head />

<body>
  <script>
    countries = ['foo'];
  </script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    document.write(countries[0]);
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

But the problem is that your PHP isn't generating valid java script. Have a look at your browser's JS console, and you'll see `ReferenceError`s because you [didn't quote the country names](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29581846/674064).

Comment: The PHP is working fine, I saw this: ´<script type="text/javascript"> countries = []; </script> <script> countries[0]= Finland;</script> <script> countries[1]= USA;</script>´, etc. and ath the end:  ´<p><script type="text/javascript">
        document.write(countries[0]);
    </script>undefined
</p>´

Comment: Edited to reflect the actual problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should use push method and Array() Construct

```
var countries = [];//nope
var countries = new Array();//yep

echo "<script> countries[".$i."]= ". $row['ShipCountry'] .";</script>";//nope
echo "<script> countries.push(".$row['ShipCountry'].");</script>";//yep
```

[push method documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/push)

Comment: How should I do that?

Comment: This is not a proper answer. Post a complete answer wit documentation and a small code snippet.

Comment: While using `push` simplifies the code, this doesn't address the question (can one JS block reference variables defined in another JS block) nor the problem the code in the question had (the generated JS was invalid). But shouldn't `push` work equally well on `[]` as on `new Array()`?